# distributed shared memory or not to be?

Tags: java, c++, interface, distributed

I need to share data between C++ client and Java server.
The Client talks to the server using `SOAP`.

The issue is - I have a generic interface serving all kinds of requests on the Java backend.
I don't want to **pollute** it with specific kind of request object which will most of the times remain null.

So I'm looking for a **creative** solution:

1. DB - C++ client writes to temporary (in memory) DB table, passes the ObjectKey to Java. Java creates an object from the record. Table is cleaned up each hour.
2. Shared Memory Cache - C++ saved object to cache, Java fetch the object.
3. `SOAP` - C++ passed the object as part of the `SOAP` request.
4. MORE - ???

This must be as efficient as possible solution.
I would love to hear other alternatives that I don't know of.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a REST approach as an alternative to SOAP. It would cut down some of the SOAP overhead. However, I think writing directly to some memory cache sounds more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared memory as ramdisk and interchange via files. also on Unix You can use UNIX sockets which is good and FAST interface for shared memory

Comment: I don't think RAM / Sockets are possible because these are separate machines connected via a TCP/IP network.

Comment: You run client and server on separate machines? - There are solutions for distributing shared memory. :)

please describe hardware platforms more verbose